# return element ID from controller to Ajax response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I send an Ajax POST call to create a new review. I'd like my controller to return the ID of the new object so I can update a couple of elements on my  web page with it. HOwever the only functional return I get is the full web page code.

Here is the Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".new_rate_restaurant").change(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var path = $(this).closest("form").attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: path,
            data: $(this).closest("form").serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);

            }
        });     

    });

});
```

Here is my controller:

```
if @review = Review.create(@attr)
            flash[:success] = "Review saved. Share with friends!"
            #render :json => @review
        else
            flash[:error] = @review.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
        end

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to @restaurant}
            format.js 
            format.json 
        end
```

Here's what has NOT worked:

putting a `render :json => @review.id` after the review is created, or in the respond_to block. At least not as it is typed in commentary under flash[:success]

Best of luck! I really hope I get some responses soon!

Comment: I don't know about ruby-on-rails, but I know something about AJAX...it always returns whatever the page on the receiving end outputs. With other words, either parse the content of the webpage you're getting or simply have it only return the ID you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `dataType` as `json` when sending request in Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    // other stuff goes here
});
```

And return new `review` id like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to @restaurant }
  format.js 
  format.json { render :json => @review }
end
```

Comment: Ilya thank you. 2 Questions if you ever drop  by this page: 1) I'm looking for a solid Ajax/ JQuery tutorial. Any tips 2) a quick tip on how to parse the object so it's readable by Ajax? Right now it returns an object and both response["name"] and response.name yield nothing. That one I'm working on but any quick tip will help me make up for lost time.